# Reusing JSF2 View Scoped Bean on facelets templating

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, facelets, backing-beans

I have a common task to choose one or more 'LocalizacaoTO' before doing anything else on the page.

Currently the logic of data retrieval/process/ajax events and so on are maintained on a `ViewScoped` bean called "SeletorLocalizacaoMB" and I’d like to use multiple instances of the same bean on the same page.

Firstly I used composite component but when I chose a node, it were stored on the last bean on the page.

If I had 3 instances declared on TesteSeletorMB:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TesteSeletorMB implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    @Getter @Setter
    private SeletorLocalizacaoMB instanceOne;
    
    @Inject
    @Getter @Setter
    private SeletorLocalizacaoMB instanceTwo;

    @Inject
    @Getter @Setter
    private SeletorLocalizacaoMB instanceThree;
}
```

No matter which component on page I used, instanceThree always hold the values.

Based on some research I understood that composite component is not the ideal solution for this problem.

So I changed the UI implementation and used Facelets to create a 'template' named seletor.xhtml.

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
    <p:dialog header="Busca Hierarquica"
              id="#{id}ModalTree"
              widgetVar="dlgSelecaoHierarquica" 
              showEffect="fade" 
              hideEffect="fade" 
              closeOnEscape="true"
              modal="#{bloqueiaModal}"
              height="400px"
              width="500px">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:commandButton id="#{id}btnSelecao" 
                             value="Selecionar e Voltar" 
                             action="#{mb['selecionarLocalHierarquico']}" 
                             update="@(.#{id}-auto-complete)" 
                             oncomplete="bloqueiaAutoMulti();"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Voltar" 
                             type="button" 
                             onclick="PF('dlgSelecaoHierarquica').hide();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:scrollPanel style="width:100%;height:350;" mode="native">
            <p:tree id="#{id}Tree"
                    style="width:100%;height:100%;" 
                    styleClass="estilo-arvore"
                    value="#{mb.arvoreHierarquica}" 
                    var="local" 
                    selectionMode="multiple" 
                    dynamic="true" 
                    animate="true">
                <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{mb['onNodeSelect']}" update="@this"/>  
                    <p:treeNode >
                        <h:outputText value="#{local.cdClasseLocal}: #{local.cdLocalizacao} #{local.niveis}" />
                    </p:treeNode>
            </p:tree>
        </p:scrollPanel>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

Test page using `<ui:include>`

```
<f:subview id="seletorAlpha">
    <ui:include src="/template/seletor.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="mb" value="#{testeSeletorMB.seletorAlpha}" />
        <ui:param name="id" value="alpha" />
    </ui:include>
</f:subview>
<f:subview id="seletorBravo">
    <ui:include src="/template/seletor.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="mb" value="#{testeSeletorMB.seletorBravo}" />
        <ui:param name="id" value="bravo" />
    </ui:include>
</f:subview>
```

Test Bean holding multiple instances:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TesteSeletorMB implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    @Getter @Setter
    private SeletorLocalizacaoMB seletorAlpha;
    
    @Inject
    @Getter @Setter
    private SeletorLocalizacaoMB seletorBravo;
}
```

CDI Bean used on 'seletor.xhtml'

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SeletorLocalizacaoMB implements Serializable {

    private List<LocalizacaoTO> locaisHierarquicosSelecionados;
    private TreeNode arvoreHierarquica;

    //PostConstruct, Ajax events and things :)
    
}
```

---

In my example, I want that TesteSeletorMB variables (seletorAlpha and seletorBravo) hold different values on their lists. Is it possible?

I tried to change SeletorLocalizacaoMB scoped to `@Dependent` but it didn't work neither. Here is where the things got confused. Reading [CDI API](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/), the first state says:

> Beans declared with scope @Dependent behave differently to beans with other >built-in scope types. When a bean is declared to have scope @Dependent:
>
> No injected instance of the bean is ever shared between multiple injection >points.

It should't hold the same instance, right?!

---

**Environment**

- WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.2
- Apache MyFaces 2.0.2
- PrimeFaces 5.0
- OmniFaces 1.7

I can provide additional data if necessary. I didn't paste all 'SeletorLocalizacaoMB' code because it has many dependencies and I had the feeling that the problem is not related to how the class handles actions.